# Android HttpURLConnect perform GET and POST consecutively

Tags: android, post, get, httpurlconnection

Basically, I would like to send a GET request to get a form and base on the value of the form to send a POST request, for example like a calculator.

```
<form action="/calc" method="POST">
  <input id="sum" name="sum" value="">
  <input id="num1" name="num1" value="6">
  <input id="num2" name="num2" value="54">
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

The value of `num1` and `num2` are change every time I send GET request using `HttpUrlConnection` in Android.

How can I get the value of HTML Element, compute the Sum in my Android App, then I send a Sum value through POST request to submit the form?

Here is my android code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MYAPP";
int rs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://local....";


    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    Log.e(TAG,response);
                    //Process the response, get value of num1 and num2 and compute the sum;
rs = sum;

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception");
        }
    });

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.e(TAG, response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error");
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("sum", String.valueOf(rs));
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(stringRequest);
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: Try to look up Retrofit. It handles this kind of stuff (Network connection) much better than handling it yourself. From there you just call two methods.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this!

Comment: Just comment when it is working so I can post a correct answer :)

Comment: I'm looking at `Volley`, that is very easy to use. However, I can't handle GET and POST at the same time. When I GET the form, parse the value and compute the result. Then, I put it to the POST request, but this time the value of the form is changed.

Comment: Why dont you do it sequentially? Show me the code you are using

Comment: I have updated my code in the question!

Comment: Try to nest thr requests